# My for loop won't output anything (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm trying to get this for loop to work on Matlab so I can plot these three histograms. I'm guessing it won't output because it says that my variables such as a_M_S1 keep changing size on every loop iteration, so the process is essentially inefficient. Any help? Below is the code.

I'm basically trying to generate 500 samples of 100 readings so I can then plot a histogram using estimated parameter values.

```
clear
clc

% Importing Data

%a = 0.9575
for m=1:500
    seed=m;
    rng(seed);
    syms x
    F=((1/atanh(0.9575))*((0.9575^(2*x-1))/(2*x-1)));
    
   for n=1:100
    data_1(n)=ceil(vpasolve(F==rand(1)));
   end     
    Data_1(m,:)=data_1;
end
        
clear
clc

Data_1=[49     1     3    17    13     3     5    51     7     1
     9     3    67     1     3     1     1     1     1    99
     5    13    21    17    41     1     1     9    23     1
     1     5     1     1    41     1    13     1     5    27
     5    37    99     1     1    33     1     1     9     1
     1     3    47    11     7     1     1    41    21    27
     5     1     1    11    45     7     3     5     1    17
    13     5     3     3     1    99     1    59     1    13
     3     5     1    35     1     1     1     1     5    19
     5     1     1     1    79     3     1     1     1     1
    31     3     1     1     1    21    69    39     1    29
     3     3     1     1     5     1     3     1     1    15
     1     1     9     1     7     1     1     1     1    11
    27     9     1     3    39     5     1     5     7     1
     1     1     7     5     1     1     3     1     3    23
     5     1    21     1     1     7     1    17     1     3
    11    11     5     1     9     1     1     1     1    37
    33     1     9     7     1     1    31    27     1     1
     5     5     1    17     3    31     1    45    37     1
     1     1    19    47     9     7     5     1     9     1
    11     1    61     5    29     1    95     1     1     1
    13    19     1     1    13     1    23     7    73     1
     1     1    11     1     5     1     3     1     7     1
    15     1     9    53     3     7     3    21     7     3
     1     7     1     1    23     7     5     1     3     1
     1     7     1     3     1     1     1     7     3     5
     1     1     1    43     7     3     1     1    21     5
     1    39     1     5    13     3     1     5     1     3
     1    11     1     1    29    17    25     1     9     1
    17     9    13    11     1     5    29     3     3     1
    65     5    63     1     1     3     5     1     7     1
    21     3     7     1     1     1    27    11    15     3
     1     1     1     1    21     1     5     3     1    11
     5     1     3     7     1     5    43     5     7    75
    29     7    83     1     3     5    15     1     1     3
     1     1     9     1    13     1    17    23     1     5
    99     1     1     1     5     7     9     3     7     1
     1    11     1    11    21     1     5     9     5     1
    33    49     3     9    15     1     1     5     1     1
     1    17     1     1     1     1    13     1     1     9
     5    13     1     1     5     3     1     1    67     1
     5     1     1     1     7    27     1    21    47     1
     1     1     1    21     3    17     1     5     5     1
     1     1    17    29    99     1     9     1     5    15
    17     5     1    13     1     1     1     1     1    21
     1    21     1     1     1    11     9    35    31    15
    99    15     1     1     9     3     1    21     1     1
     1     1     9    33     1     1    31     9    29    47
    41    99     1     7    17     5     9     3     3    13
     1    29     9     5    11     1     1     7    37    15];
 
 Data_2=[1     1     3     3     5     7     1     3     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1    13
     5     1     5     1     1     1     1     3     1     1
     1     1     3     1     1     1     1     3     1     1
     1     1    13     5     1     3     1     1     5     1
     3     3     1     7     3     5     3     1     3     1
     1     1     1     1     1     3     3     5     1     1
     1     1     1     9     1     1     1     1     5     1
     1     1     1     1     1    11     7     1     5     1
    17     1     1     7     3     7     3     5     5     1];
 
for o=1:500
    syms a
    %Method of Moments (MM)
    mean_S1 = mean(transpose(Data_1(o,:)));
    a_MM_S1(o) = vpa(vpasolve((a)/((atanh(a))*(1-a.^2)) == mean_S1,a),4);
    
    mean_S2 = mean(transpose(Data_2(o,:)));
    a_MM_S2(o) = vpa(vpasolve((a)/((atanh(a))*(1-a.^2)) == mean_S2,a),4);
    
    %Using Lower Quantile (OS)
    lower_S1 = floor(quantile(Data_1(o,:),0.25));
    a_LQ_S1(o) = vpa(vpasolve((a)/(atanh(a)) == 0.25,a),4);
    
    lower_S2 = floor(quantile(Data_2(o,:),0.25));
    a_LQ_S2(o) = vpa(vpasolve((a)/(atanh(a)) == 0.25,a),4);
    
    %Using Median (OSM)
    median_S1 = floor(quantile(Data_1(o,:),0.5));
    a_M_S1(o) = vpa(vpasolve((a)/(atanh(a)) == 0.5,a),4);
    
    median_S2 = floor(quantile(Data_2(o,:),0.5));
    a_M_S2(o) = vpa(vpasolve((a)/(atanh(a)) == 0.5,a),4);  
  
end

a_MM_S1=transpose(a_MM_S1);
a_LQ_S1=transpose(a_LQ_S1);
a_M_S1=transpose(a_M_S1);
a_MM_S2=transpose(a_MM_S2);
a_LQ_S2=transpose(a_LQ_S2);
a_M_S2=transpose(a_M_S2);

figure(1)
histogram([double(a_MM_S1),double(a_MM_S2)],20),title('Method of Moments')
figure(2)
histogram([double(a_LQ_S1),double(a_LQ_S2)],20),title('Using Lower Quartile as Estimator')
figure(3)
histogram([double(a_M_S1),double(a_M_S2)],20),title('Using Median as Estimator')
```

Comment: Symbolic math and variable-precision arithmetic are computationally expensive (i.e. slow). Are you sure you can't use normal floating-point arithmetic? But the code being slow or inefficient doesn't mean it doesn't work, so is your problem that it takes too long to produce a result, or does it really not produce a result when it completes? Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: I never completes. It just keeps going and no output ever comes out.

Comment: If you output something every loop iteration, you can track progress (e.g. `disp(o)`). Either it progresses very slowly, or it loops indefinitely. Since you only have determinate loops, the issue likely is that it progresses too slow and you’re not waiting long enough. As I said, avoiding `syms` and `vpa` will make your code much, much faster.

Comment: you have any advice on what I could use instead to solve?

Comment: Probably `fzero` is the easiest solver to use. Solving f(x)=C is the same as solving f(x)-C=0.